# Image overlaps previous view when tapping/swiping back

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIScrollView` which covers one of my views entirely. I have added  a background image to this same view which scrolls at a slightly different rate to the actual `UIScrollView`. This works absolutely fine unless I use the back swipe gesture or tap the 'Back' button. What happens is the image covers the view for about 0.5 seconds before disappearing, and it looks pretty bad.

This is what I mean:

[image]

As you can see, that is mid way through the gesture, and rather than being able to see the previous view, you just see the part of the image that is off to the left. It doesn't happen on the first page of the `UIScrollView` so I guess it's because the image is overlapping the previous view.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(images.count), height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)

    backgroundImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2484, height: 736)
    backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "SF.png")

    var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
    visualEffectView.frame = backgroundImageView.bounds

    backgroundImageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)

    view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView)

    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    loadVisiblePages()

    var factor = scrollView.contentOffset.x / (scrollView.contentSize.width - 414);
    if factor < 0 {
        factor = 0
    }
    if factor > 1 {
        factor = 1
    }

    var frame: CGRect = backgroundImageView.frame
    frame.origin.x = factor * (414 - backgroundImageView.frame.size.width)
    backgroundImageView.frame = frame
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get all your explanations but which view is the "yellow view" that we see on the right ? The one overlapping the previous view.

Comment: The yellow view on the right is the current page that is displayed in the scroll view. So that's the page that I was on when I did the back gesture. I took the screenshot while holding my finger midway through the back gesture.

Comment: Try   `self.view.clipsToBounds = true` and / or `scrollView.clipsToBounds = true` in your `viewDidLoad `

Comment: Ok I just post as the answer ;). You're welcome. Check it as correct when you see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the following in your `viewDidLoad` function:

`self.view.clipsToBounds = true` or `scrollView.clipsToBounds = true` if you just want to clip the subviews in your `UIScrollView`.

Setting this value to `true` causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is `false`.

From Apple' doc : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds